# How to fill gray space with black ? SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

How to paint a completely gray space with black ? see image
[image]
**Here is my code:**

```
.onTapGesture {
            self.showModal = true
        }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal, onDismiss: {
//            addEntry()
//            requestReviewIfNeeded()
            self.showModal = false
        }, content: {
            
            BiographyDetail(biography: self.biography)
                
            
            Button(action: {
                showModal = false
            }) {
                Text("CLOSE")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .background(Color.black).ignoresSafeArea()
            }
  
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible approach - to use color as a background and place specific content into overlay of this color.

Tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
    Color.black
        .ignoresSafeArea()   // << consumes all space
        .overlay(            // << content is overlaid 
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                BiographyDetail(biography: self.biography)


                Button(action: {
                    showModal = false
                }) {
                    Text("CLOSE")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .background(Color.black).ignoresSafeArea()
                }
            })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add frame to `Text`

```
Text("CLOSE")
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .foregroundColor(.gray)
    .background(Color.black).ignoresSafeArea()
```

Comment: it didn't work for me (the button takes up half of the screen and overlaps my content  https://i.ibb.co/Qjp80tM/IMG-8064.jpg

Comment: Use VStack and your first container and button inside the VStack.

Comment: it didn't help me either

Comment: Can you show the BiographyDetail view code?

Comment: You can try add .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) to your details view.

Comment: I cannot post the code in comments, it is very large

Comment: Put your content inside the ZStack like ZStack {Color.black, your details view, button}

Comment: this also does not work, I have already tried everything

Answer (score 0):

Text("CLOSE") .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity) .foregroundColor(.gray) .background(Color.black).ignoresSafeArea()